# How to loop and compare elements in json object and only display changes in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Basically I'm trying to display the products in a shopping cart within a div. The shopping cart is hosted elsewhere and to retrieve the products, I make a getJSON request which returns a json object like this:

```
{
"products":[
    {
        "id": "3045365",
        "name": "Test Product",
        "code": "foo123",
        "image": "",
        "url": "",
        "length": "0",
        "width": "0",
        "height": "0",
        "options": {"color":"red"},
        "quantity": 1,
        "price_each": 10,
        "price": 10,
        "weight_each": 1,
        "weight": 1,
        "shipto": "",
        "category": "DEFAULT",
        "sub_frequency": "",
        "sub_startdate": "0000-00-00",
        "sub_nextdate": "0000-00-00",
        "sub_enddate": "0000-00-00"
    },
    {
        "id": "3045366",
        "name": "Second Product",
        "code": "bar456",
        "image": "",
        "url": "",
        "length": "0",
        "width": "0",
        "height": "0",
        "options": {},
        "quantity": 1,
        "price_each": 100,
        "price": 100,
        "weight_each": 1,
        "weight": 1,
        "shipto": "",
        "category": "DEFAULT",
        "sub_frequency": "",
        "sub_startdate": "0000-00-00",
        "sub_nextdate": "0000-00-00",
        "sub_enddate": "0000-00-00"
    },
    {
        "id": "3045367",
        "name": "Example Subscription",
        "code": "xyz456",
        "image": "",
        "url": "",
        "length": "0",
        "width": "0",
        "height": "0",
        "options": {"color":"red"},
        "quantity": 1,
        "price_each": 6,
        "price": 6,
        "weight_each": 4,
        "weight": 4,
        "shipto": "",
        "category": "DEFAULT",
        "sub_frequency": "1m",
        "sub_startdate": "2010-10-15",
        "sub_nextdate": "2010-11-15",
        "sub_enddate": "2013-01-01"
    }
],
"product_count": 3,
"total_item_price": 116,
"total_discount": -5,
"total_price": 111,
"total_weight": 6,
"session_id": "9bpdjvm2ju0bulm6d7kkcf6d31",
"coupons":{
    "test2":{
        "id":"201",
        "name":"test for line item coupon discount",
        "discount":-5}
},
"custom_fields":{
    "my_hidden_value":"I'm hidden!",
    "example_hidden":"value_1"
},
"messages":{
    "errors":[],
    "warnings":[],
    "info":[]
}
}
```

My current code, when a user clicks on Add to Cart, checks to see if the div is empty. If it is, it adds the first product from the json object.

If the div isn't empty, then it compares the name of the first product in the div with the name of the first element in the json object. If the result is true, only update the price but not the name. If the result is false, it checks the next element in the json object. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

var x=0;
var y=0;

$("#addCart").click(function()
{

    if($('#cartContent').is(':empty'))
    {
        $.getJSON('https://'+storedomain+'/cart?'+fcc.session_get()+'&output=json&callback=?', function(data) 
        {
            $('#cartContent').append('<p class="name">' + data.products[x].name + '</p>' + '<p class="price">' + data.products[x].price + '</p>');      
        });
    }
    else 
    {
    $.getJSON('https://'+storedomain+'/cart?'+fcc.session_get()+'&output=json&callback=?', function(data) 
    {
            $('.name').each(function()
            {   
                while (y < data.products.length-1)
                {   
                    if($(this).text() === data.products[x].name)
                    {   
                        $('.price').eq(x).text(data.products[x].price);     
                    }   
                    x++;
                    y++;
                }
                x=0;
                y=0;
            });
            });
    }               
});
});

<a id="addCart" href="http://mydomain.foxycart.com/cart?name=test-clothes&price=10.00">Add to Cart</a>
<div id="cartContent" style="display: inline; clear: both;"></div>
```

This all works fine. My problem is I'v been testing for days but I can't come up with a method which can:

1. If user adds product 1 to cart, append name + price
2. If user adds same product 1 to cart, only update price
3. If user adds product 2 to cart, append name + price
4. If user adds same product 2 to cart, only update price

So far, my code only manages to append and compare one product. Not consecutive ones. I'm still new to javascript and if my method is ridiculous, please help me suggest a better method.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to accomplish. What is the significance of "the div is empty"?

Comment: aren't your id's the unique item not the item name? if so i'll write the loop also you don't need two vars (x and y) just one would work.  The issue appears to be you only have one .name <p> so it will only iterate once...

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals the empty div is basically a div where I'll display the appended products. Basically where my shopping cart will be.

Comment: Is it required that you only modify the existing content of `cartContent`? Or would it be acceptable to clear out and repopulate `cartContent` every time?

Comment: Agree with @AaronKurtzhals, is this a performance bottleneck? It'd be so much easier to just merge the JSON object with a template and replace everything in the div

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to map the products you add to the cart and their prices.

ex:

```
<div class="product">
    Prod 1 
    <div class="product-price">100</div>
</div>

<script>
    var productNames = [];

    function checkExisting(name) {
        return !(productNames.indexOf(name) < 0);
    }

    function appendProduct(name, price) {
        var p = $('<div>' + name + '<div>' + price + '</div></div>');
        p.data('name', name);
    }

    $(addToCart).click(function() {
        var products = $('.product');

        products.each(function() {
            if( checkExisting($(this).data('name')) ) {
                productNames.push($(this).data('name'));
            }
        });

        $.getJSON(bla, function(data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
                 if(checkExisting(data.products[i].name)) {
                     appendProduct();
                 }
                 else {
                     updatePrice();
                 }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could possible use an object (which are similar to HashMaps in other programming languages, or also associative arrays) to store the current cart state and act on future clicks after inspecting this object. You would also need to keep track of current number of products as this is not provided by JavaScript objects. It's up to you what you would store as the value

//Initially empty, or you could initialize it to the saved cart state.
var cartProducts = {}, 
    numProducts = 0;

$("#addCart").click(function () {

```
if (numProducts === 0) {
    //Here, create the DOM fragment representing your product.
    cartProducts["product-id"] = $("<div"); 

    numProducts += 1;

} else if(cartProducts["product-id"]) {
    //Update the product price since it has already been added to the DOM.

//When refactoring, combine this else statement with the first if condition.
} else {
    //At this point you know that the product has not been previously add it,
    //and can go ahead and add it to the DOM.

    //...
    numProducts += 1;        
}
```

});

Just **general comments** on your code structure:

1. Commenting your code would help others and you in the future to understand your code.
2. Try to modularize your code into separate functions that are responsible for a small chunks of code. This will help with the code manageability, reuseability, and testability.
3. Use for loops instead of while loops if you are going to iterate [i->n; i++].
4. [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) your code to help you with styling and proper syntax.

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

The below code is how i'd do it:

```
    //occurs when the element with id addCart is clicked
$("#addCart").click(function()
{
    //gets json of products
    $.getJSON('https://'+storedomain+'/cart?'+fcc.session_get()+'&output=json&callback=?', function(data) 
    {
        //creates arrays to hold values
        var items = new Array();
        var names = new Array();
        var price = new Array();

        //foreach product in data name it item and do the following
        data.products.each(function(item){
            //See if the item id is in the items array
            var index = $.inArray(item.id, items);
            //If it isn't
            if(index == -1)
            {
                //Add the item to the arrays
                items.push(item.id);
                names.push(item.name);
                price.push(item.price);
            }
            //it already is in the array one time so just add to price
            else
            {
                //add to the price by the amount of the item price
                price[index] += item.price;
            }
        });

        //empty the html from the element with id cartContent 
        $('#cartContent').empty();
        //loop through all items in item array
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length ; i++) {
            //Add html for each item since we only added each once this happens once per item
            $('#cartContent').append('<p class="name">' + names[i] + '</p>' + '<p class="price">' + price[i] + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd definitely add quantity to this because it is really confusing currently.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I think I might do it this way since it's more logical for me. However I don't quite understand all of the functions in your code above. Are you able to add a few comments to help me better understand it?  Thank You

Comment: added comments! let me know if you need more help